# Update listbox in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I currently have a C# application for the purpose of testing specific parameters on a device. I have created the application with a separate class for dealing with tests. I would like to have the list box update automatically after every item is added to it from the "Test Class".

The "MainWindow" class I have for the UI creates a new "Test" class on button click..

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window{


    //Other initializing steps..

        private void BeginTestButton_Click(..){
            TestClass tc = new TestClass(this); //<-- passing this class in
            tc.testAll();
        } 
}
```

where the testAll function inside the "TestClass" looks something like this..

```
    public void testAll(){
        view.getListBox().add(test1()); 
        view.getListBox().add(test2());
        view.getListBox().add(test3());
        // and so on
    }
```

Where view is the UI class and the `getListBox()`is the listbox in question. Each "test" performed returns some string which would be the result of the test.

What methods are available to me for having these test results added to a list box and update after each test is finished? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do something with the TestClass, likely have it extend INotifyPropertyChanged.  From there you can add a property on the TestClass.  Adjust your listbox to show more than just a string/tag, if you haven't, like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="{Binding TestName}"></Label>
                <Label Content="{Binding TestCompleteStatus}"></Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Then, Whenever you kick off your test, you'll need to change your TestCompleteStatus property in the TestClass (make sure to do this on the UI thread or with dispatcher, as you'll be bound to the UI now).  After your property has changed the ListBox will automatically update with the new property value.  This is the functionality of INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Just for clarification, I just need to make sure that the UI thread sees that the value of CompleteStatus for every test?

Comment: If your tests are executing on a separate thread, you'll just need to make sure they update the CompleteStatus on the UI thread.  If you're not using another thread to run these tests, then you don't need to worry.  If you are, it's as simple as doing App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate{ Test1.CompleteStatus = "result"; })); The dispatcher always runs on the UI thread and will make sure you don't get cross thread issues.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void testAll(){
    view.getListBox().add(test1()); 
    view.getListBox().add(test2());
    view.getListBox().add(test3());
    // and so on
  }
```

You Need To change test1() from void to any func ex:

```
  int test1(){

 // now retern value
  return 0;
 }

    public void testAll(){
    view.getListBox().add(Convert.ToInt32(test1())); 

    }
```